# Get all users from sharepoint site using client side code(SP-App)

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, groups, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to get all users in all groups from my Sharepoint-Site, is this possible? if so, how do I do this?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32040/list-of-all-users-having-access-to-at-least-one-site-in-the-site-collection

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Azure AD Graph REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog) for that purpose, in particular [Get User(s)  operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151678.aspx), for example:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX ... FWSXfwtQ
Content-Type: application/json
Host: graph.windows.net
```